# For which a and b is $\int_0^{1/2} r^{a+n-1}|\log(r)|^b dr<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

The problem I am working on asks which real values of a and b make $|x|^a|\log|x||^b$ integrable over $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: |x| < 1/2\}$, but I reinterpret the question to asking which real values of a and b make $\int_0^{1/2} r^{a+n-1}|\log(r)|^b dr<\infty$. The trouble now is I'm not clear on how to check this inequality over all of $\mathbb{R}$. Actually, guessing and checking hasn't found me a single pair of values for which the integral isn't finite, which I'm sure would be far too easy and anyway I wouldn't know how to prove it.

I just need a hint on how to rigorously check the finiteness of this integral, or if this is the wrong approach to the problem, what the right approach might be.

Comment: Your reduction of the problem is a good idea, but note that you are implicitly using n-d polar coords. The value of $a$ will be shifted by a factor.

Comment: It might just be because I'm very tired, but I'm not sure what you mean by "n-d polar coords". is "n-d" an abbreviation for something or a subtraction..?

Comment: You can write $\int_{R^n} f(|x|) dx = \omega_n \int_0^\infty f(r)r^{n-1}dr$ where $\omega_n$ is the surface area of the $n$-sphere. I meant n-d as in n-dimensional.

Comment: Okay, you're right. I've edited the question accordingly, but I think I still have the same problem with the resulting function.

Comment: This is probably closely related to things that you already know. Everything will be OK if $y\gt -1$. And things will be bad if $y\lt -1$. The $\log$ gets into the game only when $a=-1$. In that case, we will have convergence if $b\lt -1$, and divergence otherwise. We need to prove all these things. None of the items is hard, but there are several. Note this is for the original question $\int_0^{1/2} y^a(|\log y|)^b\,dy$. The question has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1/2}r^{a + n - 1}\verts{\ln\pars{r}}^{b}\,\dd r < \infty:\
     {\large ?}}$

> With $\ds{\quad r \equiv \expo{t}\quad\imp\quad t = \ln\pars{r}}$\begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1/2}r^{a + n - 1}\verts{\ln\pars{r}}^{b}\,\dd r}
> =-\int_{\infty}^{2}r^{- a - n - 1}\ln^{b}\pars{r}\,\dd r
> =\int_{\ln\pars{2}}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{a + n + 1}t}t^{b}\pars{\expo{t}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{\ln\pars{2}}^{\infty}t^{b}\expo{-\pars{a + n}t}\,\dd t
> \quad\mbox{which converges when}\quad\pars{a + n} > 0\quad\mbox{and}\quad b > -1
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{1/2}r^{a + n - 1}\verts{\ln\pars{r}}^{b}\,\dd r}
={1 \over \pars{a + n}^{b + 1}}\int_{\pars{a + n}\ln\pars{2}}^{\infty}t^{b}
\expo{-t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large%
{\Gamma\pars{b + 1,\pars{a + n}\ln\pars{2}} \over \pars{a + n}^{b + 1}}}\,,\qquad
\pars{a + n} > 0\,,\quad b > - 1
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Gamma\pars{s,x}}$ is the
[Incomplete Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Comment: $\ln(2)<0$ so when $b<0$ then $t^b$ is ill-defined. Some more care is needed with the change of variables?

Comment: @nayrb $\large\ln\left(2\right) \approx 0.6931 > 0$.

Comment: Duh. Sorry to waste your time. It's late where I am.

Comment: @nayrb Don't worry. It happens to me several times. Thanks.